# image vs texture size LWJGL

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, slick2d

### First Scenerio

1. Loaded a texture with `Stick-util.jar`, where the image size = *50x50* & texture size =*64x64*.
2. Bound the texture & drew a Quad of size *64x64*. And gives out an Image of size *50x50*.

Grid of size *50x50*

[image: Grid of size 50x50]

### Second Scenerio

1. Loaded another texture of Image size = 180x50, but texture size = 256x64

### Question

It's obvious that `slick-util` is converting the texture size to some power of 2. And when bound, drawing its original size. (default)

But **why & how**? The second texture's width to height ratio is not equal to the image size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why** is simply because some older GPUs only support power-of-two textures.

**How** is difficult to answer, because it is implementation specific. It either uses texcoords to only show the part of the texture that was from the initial image, or it fills the extra texture space with alpha=0 texels that are rejected when drawing. I'm only speculating though.

Comment: Yes, extra texels filled with alpha=0. The reason for the power of two is because of migmaps & how powers of 2 help GPUs to draw transformation accurately. IMHO [Texture wiki @openGL](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Texture)